# Building a maven project with external JNI libraries

Tags: java, maven-2, java-native-interface, executable-jar

I'm developing a program on MacOSx that uses third party jar files that all use JNI to call C functions.

How can I include those on my build path and set the java.library.path to use the external dependencies properly ?
I would like to avoid having to install anything in my maven repository. This is important since I'll have to deploy my program to other linux platforms as well, which already have those third-party jars and C libraries installed somewhere...

For now what I've done is adding my jar dependencies with scope=system and systemPath pointing to the full path of my jar files, but I don't know how to set the os-specific dependencies...

Regards,

Philippe

Comment: For now, I'm just putting the JNI-dependent jar files in my maven dependencies, then I launch my executable jar file with -Djava.library.path=/my/path/to/c_libs_folder -jar myexecutable.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>foo</groupId>
          <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
          <systemPath>/my/path/to/c_libs_folder/myexecutable.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```